# Nonparametric theory textbook(s)?

Tags: references, nonparametric

I am looking for a nonparametric statistical theory textbook that does **not** avoid tools from measure-theoretic probability and covers proofs on topics **outside** of rank-based hypothesis tests: e.g., kernel density estimation, nonparametric estimation, and resampling methods (i.e., bootstrapping, jackknife).

The closest textbook I can find to this is Tsybakov's *Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation*. What can I use to supplement this textbook?

Wasserman's *All of Nonparametric Statistics* has the appropriate topic coverage, but does not really cover proofs.

Comment: Do you think Tsybakov's book is good for beginners who want an introduction that isn't as proof or measure theory heavy? I searched for it and found some small previews which make it seem good, but I couldn't tell for sure.

Comment: @roundsquare If you want to avoid proofs and measure theory entirely, something like Bishop's *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* would do.

Comment: Thanks @Clarinetist. I took a look at the table of contents - it doesn't seem to be focused on nonparametric estimation - at least to me since I don't know much about the subject. Is that the focus of Bishop's book?

Comment: @roundsquare It is not, but it covers the basics avoiding measure theory and proofs. In all honesty, I haven't seen a single nonparametric estimation that avoids proofs entirely. Another book to consider might be *Semiparametric Regression* by Ruppert, Wand, and Carroll - but be warned, this text is quite dense. I would honestly recommend you ask a question too; you'll probably get better recommendations that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for asking this question! I only saw rank-based proofs before since the nonparametrics course clashed with other coursework I had to take. After finding Györfi *et al*'s book, I also picked up a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend *A Distribution-Free Theory of Nonparametric Regression* by Györfi, Kohler, Krzyżak and Walk. It looks like what you are looking for: proofs use sigma fields as needed, there is plenty of use of dominated convergence and Fatou's Lemma, and it hits topics like kernels and k-nearest neighbors.

The [online notes from László Györfi](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/booknonpar.pdf) seem like a smaller (*i.e.* much less complete) version of what you are looking for: there are sigma fields, dominated convergence proofs, etc. Maybe take a peek at that to see if you want to investigate the larger book by him and coauthors.

Answer (score 1):

There's a chapter in this book on nonparametric statistics: "Modern Statistical Methods for Astronomy With R Applications", Feigelson and Babu https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/astronomy-general/modern-statistical-methods-astronomy-r-applications?format=HB&isbn=9780521767279